# HLK Studio does not show my driver in selection tab

Tags: testing, kernel, driver

I am trying to do HLK testing for my own driver by this instruction https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/hardware/dn915002(v=vs.85).aspx , but I have problems.

I can not do step 5 as I do not see my driver in the list of .sys files I can select for testing in HLK Studio selection tab.
My driver is stored on test machine in location C:\MyDriver\mydriver64.sys. It is 64-bit kernel mode driver used by my application for RAM analysis.

What can I do to add my driver to the selection list and run HLK tests for it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the driver is running on the machine
2. Make sure the machine status is set to ready.
3. Restart the HLK service on client. (go to services, search for hlk, R-click, restart)
4. Restart the HLK service on server. (same as client)
5. Check the machine status again, give it some minutes to get ready
6. If still not working, try restarting both systems

Comment: Can anyone please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61520874/test-system-is-not-shown-in-hlk-controller

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes HCK Infrastucture Service crashing, but HLK Communication service still works. You need restart HCK Infrastructure service too. On my job, we had a problem with very long start time of this service and Windows throws timeout error for service start. Because of this, service never starts. We solved this problem, by setting bigger time for service start in Windows registry.
Registry key is `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServicesPipeTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the driver is running on the test machine.
2. Start "HLK Manager", click on "My Machines..."
3. Select your test machine from the list, right click, "change-status" to "unsafe"
4. Open "HLK Studio" ... "Configuration"
5. Find your test machine, right click, "change machine status" to "ready"
6. Load your project and check for your driver under "Selection"

---

What kind is your driver? Please provide your inf file or registry entry.
Do you search it under "software device" or "device manager"?

Comment: You should work on ensuring your spelling and grammar are correct when posting an answer. Also, you should refrain from asking questions in an answer. That's what comments are for.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. Yet I don't have 50 reputation for adding a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to

- install driver prior to client
- start driver
- select **software device** in Studio's **Selection** tab

I was looking for my driver in "device manager" which was the default and not finding it as it is a driver hence software.  Spent far more time on that problem than I'd like to admin

Answer (score 0):

1. Restart Client Machine
2. Restart HLK Communication service.
3. Restart HLK Infra Service.
   Now try to load the machine pool, Issue should have resolved now.